# How does SPF reduce backscatter with a Google Apps account

Tags: g-suite, spf

Reading up on the SPF spec, I understand that SPF designates certain IPs as valid sender SMTP server IPs. For Google Apps, the SPF record is supposed to be `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`.

The way I read this, it means allow ANYONE with a Gmail/Google Apps account to spoof an email address from my domain name.

So how does this really reduce spam? Is the assumption here that spammers don't/can't create throwaway gmail addresses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suspect that Google is not going to allow another user to spoof email from your Google Apps domain using their servers.

Change `~all` to `-all` after adding any other authorized outbound mail servers to the list. Ambiguous SPF records are almost pointless, and there is limited anecdotal evidence within the ServerFault community that `~all` may harm your domain's spam reputation.

Comment: Indeed, part of the bargain you make when you outsource email like Google Apps is to trust the vendor to prevent such impersonation attacks.

Comment: Regarding the `~all`, I had reservations, but Google recommends using it. Just a few minutes ago, on a related question, the author to one of the answers (http://serverfault.com/a/550859/32522) confirmed I don't need to use `~all`. That resonates with your feedback. As for the question I asked, your answer confirms that SPF by itself doesn't really prevent the scenario I mentioned. I wanted to clarify that for myself. I suppose Google must have implemented safe guards. Thanks!

Comment: My 2¢, I'm part of that anecdotal evidence he mentions. Some of the servers I control rank your e-mail more likely to be spam if you have a "~" in your SPF record. I doubt this is a common practice, but I can't be the only one.